# CSS Bootstrap Border-bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I try to put a `border-bottom` on my bootstrap navigation `li`'s, the `padding` makes it so that the whole button (not the word) is underlined by the `border-bottom`. What I want to accomplish is that, only the word inside the `li > a` is underlined. 
I have removed any `padding` in the **bootstrap.css** file, now all the words are right against each other.

Comment: can you create a demo what you tried sofar?

Comment: `li>a{border-bottom: 1px solid black !important}`?

Comment: `li > a{ text-decoration:underline}` ??

Comment: I have actually solved the problem myself, I'll give you the solution here. All I needed to do was add the border-bottom to the `.nav > li > a` instead of the `.nav > li`. Thank you for the reponses :)

Comment: add an answer to the question here and later mark it as solved. Writing solved does not actually make this question solved. and putting it in the comments is not appropriate.

Comment: also... don't use border-bottom... use text-decoration: underline to... underline... a word. Like the answer below has.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the native bootstrap3 styles, you'll need the specificity that is inherent in the bootstrap style.  You'll probably want to put back in the padding you lost.  Add this style to your individual style sheet that is linked after the bootstrap stylesheet or add to the end of the bootstrap stylesheet:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```